# Replacing different numbers of whitespace with 2 spaces Python

Tags: python, replace, whitespace, strip

I am opening a binary file to write to a txt file. I need to remove some lines of the code before writing it to the text so I do this with the following code:

```
with open(rawfile) as f, open(outfile,'w') as f2:
for x in f:
    if (':') not in x and ('Station') not in x and('--')not in x and('hPa') not in x:
        f2.write(x.strip()+'\n')
```

This produces several columns of data like:

```
   Header  Header    Header   Header
   Data    Data  Data     Data  
    Data   Data    Data     Data
```

As you can see, there are varying number of space between each string in each column/row. While keeping the columns and rows intact, all I need to do is replace the varying number of spaces to be 2 spaces evenly between all data strings. I tried making another for statement but could not figure out how to keep it all to one file and have it overwrite the file everytime.

EDIT WITH DATA SNIPPET:

```
PRES   HGHT   TEMP   DWPT   FRPT   RELH   RELI   MIXR   DRCT   SKNT   
1002.0     53   32.4   23.4   23.4     59     59  18.47    345     10  
1000.0     65   31.0   19.0   19.0     49     49  14.03    340     10  
999.0     74   30.4   19.4   19.4     52     52  14.41    339     10 
996.0    101   30.1   19.5   19.5     53     53  14.54    335     10  
972.0    318   28.1   20.3   20.3     63     63  15.64    355     10  
959.0    437   26.9   20.7   20.7     69     69  16.29    340     11
932.0    692   24.5   21.6   21.6     84     84  17.74      0      5  
931.0                                                       1      5  
925.0                                                      10      5  
888.0                                            12.88     95     13
```

Additionally, I cannot have the data become bunched up in those large blank spaces. Data needs to remain under its associated header (this is a text file and not a dataframe)

Comment: `'  '.join(x.split())` replaces all whitespace in a string `x` with 2 spaces

Comment: I probably wasn't clear. I was mainly confused where to put that given the code I already have.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```py
header_len = 0
for x in f:
    if (':') not in x and ('Station') not in x and('--')not in x and('hPa') not in x:
        line = x.strip()+'\n'
        line_parts = line.split(' ')

        if header_len == 0:
          header_len = len(line_parts[0])
        elif len(line_parts[0]) < header_len:
          line_parts = [lp + ' ' * (header_len - len(lp)) for lp in line_parts]

        while '' in line_parts:
          line_parts.remove('')
        f2.write('  '.join(line_parts))
```

Comment: Some of the columns have a blank space and I would need all the data to remain underneath its associated header. The above code bunches the lines with missing data together, putting them in a different column.

Comment: Hacked together something else with list composition

Comment: Gives the same result with the rows that have blank data getting bunched together. Will have to explore ways outside of python